# algorithm Matlab function 'stream2' and 'stream3' use to compute streamline

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot

Can anyone explain how the MATLAB functions: `stream2(x,y,z,u,v,startx,starty)` and `stream3(x,y,z,u,v,startx,starty)` compute stream lines from vector data `u` and `v`? In the `stream2.m` file, it calls the `stream3c` function. I assume it is a `.c` file but unable to see it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't find the file, then it's most likely implemented in MEX.  For `stream3c` it is.  Type in `edit stream3c` and you'll see that the only statement in that code is a MEX related error check... so yup, implemented in MEX.  In that case, you definitely can't find it.  You can however understand how it works through: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/visualizing-vector-volume-data.html

Comment: One more comment.  I managed to find where this file is.  It's under `$matlabroot/toolbox/matlab/specgraph/private`.  However, you're still out of luck as there is only the `mex` file that is associated with the function.  This is the fully compiled source as an executable function, but you don't have access to the source itself.  In this case, you're [SOL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SOL).  Sorry!

Comment: If you know the file name you can always google it. The MEX source file is `stream3c.c` and [here](http://www.ligo-wa.caltech.edu/~cheryl.vorvick/etmx2007/OldStuffFromPCLaptop/MATLAB6p1/toolbox/matlab/specgraph/private/src/stream3c.c "the file itself") is the file itself. Do you need explanation for the code?

Comment: Please! I'm not familiar with C, so if you could explain a little the algorithm, it will be very helpful. Just basic ideas, how it turns input arguments, u,v,w, into output, which the stream2.m file says is "a cell array of vertex arrays". Thanks.

Comment: I was just trying to understand what's hidden in the MEX. Thanks anyway.